# Storing different id's in mongodb notification schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, notifications

I'm trying to implement notifications into my app but I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the id's of the sender and receiver into my notification schema below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const notificationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    sender: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }],
    receiver: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }],
    seen: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    notificationMessage: {
        type: String
    },
    created: { 
        type: Date
    }
})

const Notifications = mongoose.model('notification', notificationSchema);
module.exports = Notifications;
```

I have a controller trying to create a new notification below

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const Notification = require('../models/Notification');

module.exports = {

    getNotifications: async (req, res, next) => {
        const { _id } = req.params;
        const user = await User.findById(_id).populate('notification');
        console.log('user', user)
        res.status(200).json(user.notifications);
    },

createNotification: async (req, res, next) => {
    const { _id } = req.params;
    const newNotification = new Notification(req.body);
    console.log('newNotification', newNotification);
    const user = await User.findById(_id);
    newNotification.user = user;
    await newNotification.save();
    let sender = new User({id: user._id});
    newNotification.sender.push(sender);
    let receiver = new User({id: user._id});
    newNotification.receiver.push(receiver);
    await user.save();
    res.status(201).json(newNotification);
}
}
```

The problem is once I try to create a notification, nothing is stored, the notification schema returns with this.

```
newNotification { sender: [], receiver: [], _id: 5bd1465d08e3ed282458553b }
```

I'm not entirely sure how I can go about storing the user id's into their respective references in the notification schema, any idea on what I can do to fix this?

**EDIT:** changed createNotification

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store `ObjectId` in the array but adding the whole `user` object and mongoose schema doesn't allow fields which are not defined in the schema so change `newNotification.sender.push(user._id)` in the `createNotification` function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please? I've changed user.notification.push(newNotification) to what you suggested but now I'm getting (node:10092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: its because earlier I missed to add `sender` before push. Try with updated ans for both sender and receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **variable** name when **push user** data in **notification**

```
let sender = new User({id: user._id, name: user.name}):
newNotification.sender.push(sender); //for store sender

let reciever = new User({id: user._id, name: user.name}):
newNotification.receiver.push(reciever); //for store reciever
```

Comment: Just tried this out but both sender and receiver fields are still empty. Is there anything else I could try to help? Thanks

Comment: @Sharkows Abel Plz try my updated answer may help you

Comment: So now, the notification schema is saving both the sender and receiver id's but in the user schema the notifications field is still empty and I'm getting Type:Error Cannot read property 'id' of null. Any idea what could be happening? Thanks for sticking with me this long

Comment: can you please provide what you have changes?

Comment: Edited post with your changes